# Team members creating application on shared domain

Tags: openshift

I have added some team members to a domain. I already have three gears under my name -- if they create a gear in the domain I shared, does that gear count towards my gear-count (thereby putting me over the 3-small free limit) or does that gear count towards their gear count?

Can't find any information about this on the openshift support website.

I have my credit card there for the upgrade to Bronze so my apps don't spin down, and I don't want any accidental charges because they created gears!

Comment: Stackoverflow if for programming related problems. You should ask this question on  [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: It's off topic there too. Shame because red hat has yet to get back to me on this. Thanks anyway, I'll delete the question.

Comment: You asked a good question. Let me find a right place. Dont delete it. Ok

Comment: Ok I'll hold off on deleting. Thanks for trying, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In OpenShift, if you give your collaborators access to create applications, additional gears will be chargeable at standard price from your credit card.**

In OpenShift, any creation or updation of gears in your domain, even by your collaborators, will be considered as a operation performed with your permission .

Here is the message that you will get when you click the **Add a collaborator** link on the right side on your OpenShift [applications page](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications):

> You can give a collaborator access to your domains and applications. **Adding someone** as an editor on a domain **gives them the ability** to create or update **your** applications.

And Here is description of what these collaborators can do based on your assigned access for a domain at https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/domain/mydomainname

> What can members do?
>
> > View – Read-only access to the domain and its applications.
> >
> > Edit – Add, edit, control and delete applications in the domain, including SSH and Git access
> >
> > Administer – Everything except change allowed gear sizes and the domain name.

So, This is how it works:

- If you give collaborators **View access**, they will not be able to create applications. So no additional gear creation and **no additional charge**.
- If you give collaborators **Edit access** or **Administer access**, they will be able to create application and can choose any gear size that you permitted for domain. So **additional gears created** and **additional charges apply** accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I wasn't reading into context clues enough.

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola It Happens Bro. Its good to see you dont deleted this good question

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola Further Reading: [Resource Management in OpenShift Applications](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/resource-management.html)